# DocuSign - Not able to transfer templates to production account

Tags: docusignapi

We got our demo account approved for production. I am trying to export the templates from sandbox account and upload to production but it throws me a "Request failed with status code 400" when I try to upload template.

Comment: you are doing that using the API? you can just do that manually. But if your app/integration has functionality to do that, maybe share your code? also, did you just started using production? you may need to update your configuration

Comment: I am trying to upload the template to production account using the web interface and it says "Request failed with status code 400" on the interface. My code works with the templates I have on the sandbox account.

Comment: this sounds like a bug. If you want to contact support - that's one option. If there's nothing proprietary/secret in your template - email it to me and I can check this

Comment: The code is for my client, as per agreement, I can't disclose here. We are going to contact support and I will update here what the issue was.

Comment: I answered below what I suspect is the issue. Do you use any premium features in the template? they may not be available in the production account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the bug here is that you are not getting a nice/useful error message.
My guess is that you may have used some paid feature in demo that you did not purchase in production for one of these templates and that is why you cannot load them in production. The error message should indicate this. I am not certain that's the issue, but that's an option.

Comment: Very close answer but the issue was fixed by enabling option in the DS settings called "Enable custom email and language for each recipient". If you can, adjust the answer. I will accept it.

Comment: The error msg only said error 400. I had to digg into the POST calls to find the error. DS should just show the error the user.